# Use a generic function to do stuff based on the caller?

Tags: python

I have this code which makes it easy to color a string in terminal but it is looking really repetitive. Is there a functional way of doing this more effectively?

It seems really trival, something like strings `blue`,`red` etc should point to a generic function, and when you invoke it, you should get the output depending on the caller's name!

But apparently such a thing doesn't exist unless I call it as arguements. But then I lose the flexibility of writing `blue(bold(italics("Foo")))` which is really the best way to do this from an end user perspetive.

Can I have a single function object in the memory and do this more effectively?

```
bcolors = {"BLUE": '\033[94m',
           "HIGH": '\033[93m',
           "OKAY": '\033[92m',
           "FAIL": '\033[91m',
           "BOLD": '\033[1m',
           "LINE": '\033[4m',
           "ENDC": '\033[0m'
           }

def blue(string):
    return bcolors["BLUE"] + string + bcolors["ENDC"]


def yellow(string):
    return bcolors["HIGH"] + string + bcolors["ENDC"]


def green(string):
    return bcolors["OKAY"] + string + bcolors["ENDC"]


def red(string):
    return bcolors["FAIL"] + string + bcolors["ENDC"]


def bold(string):
    return bcolors["BOLD"] + string + bcolors["ENDC"]


def line(string):
    return bcolors["LINE"] + string + bcolors["ENDC"]
```

Comment: A function should never vary its behaviour depending on *who* called it; only its arguments should influence its behaviour, anything else is madness.

Comment: Yes that pure functional programming, I agree. So basically there are no solutions to this problem than creating so many function objects? I just wanted to re-affirm that.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're so fond of `blue(bold(italics("Foo")))`. I prefer something like `style("Foo", BLUE, BOLD, ITALICS)`, where the style args are all optional and can be given in any order. Also, my way makes it easier to eliminate redundant `'\033[0m'` sequences.

Comment: Thats also a nice way to think about this! I somehow had my head on functional programming constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about build them on the fly?:

```
bcolors = {"BLUE": '\033[94m',
           "HIGH": '\033[93m',
           "OKAY": '\033[92m',
           "FAIL": '\033[91m',
           "BOLD": '\033[1m',
           "LINE": '\033[4m',
           "ENDC": '\033[0m'
           }

def _genF(color):
    return lambda s: bcolors[color] + s + bcolors["ENDC"]

globals().update({k.lower():_genF(k) for k,v in bcolors.items()})

In[10]: blue("Foo")
Out[10]: '\x1b[94mFoo\x1b[0m'
In[11]: blue(bold(okay("Foo")))
Out[11]: '\x1b[94m\x1b[1m\x1b[92mFoo\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m'
```

This way yo can just use the bcolors dict info for boulding all the methods you need just modifiying the dict.

Comment: Isn't building on the fly more costlier? I am also trying to reduce the memory footprints as much as possible.

Comment: The documentation of `locals` notes, that it is not guaranteed, but implementation dependent if updating the returned dictionary will actually effect the local scope. This is not the case with `globals()`, which returns a dictionary that is guaranteed to propagate updates to the global scope.

Comment: If you look outputs, it always returns `\x1b[4m` for the start sequence. When you define a function inside loop, you need to use keyword parameter to work-around this: `lambda s, k=k: ....`

Comment: acutally it is `globals()` wich should be used, thanks @Callidior

Comment: @falsetru, correct thanks, but shouldnt it be building a new one for each key? this behaviour is ugly :/

Comment: @DanielSanchez, It's an expected behavior. `k` is not bound at function definition time, but at run time.

Comment: @falsetru, in fact thats why, k should be diferent in each "iteration" since it is not bound at definition(thats  how my mind sees it), but is good to know it like that now :)

Comment: @DanielSanchez, Because `k` is overwritten in a loop and references the last key after the loop. BTW, it would be better to update the previous output with actual output after the code change.

Comment: @falsetru, ok, i understand it now!!, yeah, the behaviour is expected now, i missed that part, thanks for all :D

Comment: @DanielSanchez We are still creating n no: of function objects here right? Yes its more easier than explictly doing it however ...

Comment: @Nishant, yes you are still creating the functions in memory, but is still the only way of doin a call like `blue(bold(okay("Foo")))`

Comment: @Nishant These function objects are lightweight, as they all share the same code object (the lambda). As long as you don't create literally millions of them, you don't need to worry about the memory spent on those.

Answer (score 1):

A function should never vary its behaviour depending on who called it; only its arguments should influence its behaviour, anything else is madness.

The obvious refactoring to make it dryer here would be something along these lines:

```
def _format(start, string):
    return bicolors[start] + string + bcolors['ENDC']

def blue(string):
    return _format('BLUE', string)
```

If you wrap this in a class with some magic properties or method call overrides, you could even start deriving the `'BLUE'` parameter from the function call.

Comment: Class methods change depending on the context which is also my use case here. However, I was told that doing it using a method is not a good way to tackle this problem? Something like class method would do this formatting based on self.style attribute, now I end up creating n color objects and have one class method that does this work of formatting strings. I can also make the object return to just call the method directly perhaps using the `__call__` attribute. Does that make sense? Is that a good way to solve this in your opinion?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: Does that make sense now? Just curious to know if I could put across my point! Functions should not depend on outside contexts, however class methods don't have this limitation, and yet it is a function, hence I was thinking of this approach as well.